# Shortcut for creating the same action for multiple items in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

In my current project on multiple occasions I've had to perform the same action for several different EditTexts.

For example, if I were to clear out several EditTexts at once, is there an easier way than manually typing out:

```
et1.setText(null);
et2.setText(null); 
et3.....
```

I'm currently doing the same things for seven different EditTexts and it is tedious to type out the same actions for all of them.  Is there a way to speed up the typing process when the only thing that changes is the item I am performing the action on?

Answer (score 1):

Store them in an array and loop over the array, clearing them all.  If you have to do it multiple places, make it a function.  Don't obsess over the typing speed-  typing is less than 5% of the time you spend on a project.  Worry about the maintainability.  The main problem isn't how long it takes, its the high likelihood you'll forget one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [Gabe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38296377/1306419). However for completeness sake, if you want to speed up typing for certain situation, you can use <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> if you are on mac or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> on Windows. This will copy and paste the current line. If you want to copy paste piece of code, then just select those line and use the above shortcut keys.